# Parse CSS Color to RGBA values

Tags: javascript, colors

I want get RGBA values from some <color> CSS data type values.

The function should accept a string which describe some color, and return an object with red, green, blue, and, alpha values.

for example:

```
parseColor('red') -> { red: 255, green: 0, blue: 0, alpha: 1 }
parseColor('#f00') -> { red: 255, green: 0, blue: 0, alpha: 1 }
parseColor('rgb(255,0,0)') -> { red: 255, green: 0, blue: 0, alpha: 1 }
parseColor('hsla(0,100%,50%,0.1)') -> { red: 255, green: 0, blue: 0, alpha: 0.1 }
parseColor('transparent') -> { red: any_is_ok, green: any_is_ok, blue: any_is_ok, alpha: 0 }
```

So, I tried codes like this:

```
function parseColor(color) {
  var x = document.createElement('div');
  document.body.appendChild(x);
  var color, rgba;
  var red = 0, green = 0, blue = 0, alpha = 0;
  try {
    x.style = 'color: ' + color + '!important';
    color = window.getComputedStyle(x).color
    rgba = color.match(/rgba?\((.*)\)/)[1].split(',').map(Number);
    red = rgba[0];
    green = rgba[1];
    blue = rgba[2];
    alpha = '3' in rgba ? rgba[3] : 1;
  } catch (e) {
  }
  x.parentNode.removeChild(x);
  return {'red': red, 'green': green, 'blue': blue, 'alpha': alpha};
}
```

It works in both Firefox, IE, and Chrome.
But I wonder what `window.getComputedStyle(x).color` would return?
Will this function **always** return color in `rgb()` or `rgba()` format?
What the specification say?

And, is there any other way to implement the `parseColor` function?

Comment: `window.getComputedStyle(x).color` returns what the documents say it returns. See https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/Window/getComputedStyle. To find other ways to do it, you could google "npm html color". That would lead you to things like this: https://github.com/substack/parse-color. See also http://stackoverflow.com/questions/11068240/what-is-the-most-efficient-way-to-parse-a-css-color-in-javascript.

Comment: @torazaburo It seems that `parse-color` or `color-convert` (which is used by `parse-color`) do not support alpha value (transparency).

Comment: @tsh you swapped green and blue. it should read `blue = rgba[2];` and `green = rgba[1];`.

Comment: @Roberg aha, thank you for pointing out my mistook. edited.

Answer (score 0):

`parseColor` function works by creating dummy element and set color to it.So it can get color in rgba() or rgb() (it depends on what parameter `color` is) 
but the result will always be in rgba() because

```
alpha = '3' in rgba ? rgba[3] : 1;
```

it means if there is no alpha(a) it will set to 1