# How to return rgba value from window.getComputedStyle() or other function?

Tags: javascript, css

I have a div with applied some inline style as `rgba(0,255,0,1)` and I am using `...style.borderColor` to return a string with its color value.

I have noticed if alpha channel is 1 (no transparency) the value returned is only in `rgb` format, if instead color applied as some transparency like `rgba(0,255,0,0.5)` values is returned correctly in `rgba`.

- Do you know any way to force an `rgba` (with alpha) to be returned instead?
- If no how could I add this value, string manipulation is a good way?

```js
var elm = document.querySelector('#target');
console.log(elm.style.borderColor);
```

```html
<div id="target" style="  width: 150px;  height:150px;  background-color:red;  border-color: rgba(0,255,0,1);   border-width: 20px;   border-style: solid;"></div>
```

Comment: There are some interesting avenues to follow in this thread. http://stackoverflow.com/questions/11068240/what-is-the-most-efficient-way-to-parse-a-css-color-in-javascript

Comment: Why do you need this? If you want to modify the color, CSS Color Level 4 plans to introduce functions to modify colors.

Comment: @Oriol interesting could you please send me a link?

Comment: @Radex https://drafts.csswg.org/css-color/#modifying-colors but I don't think any browser supports this already.

Comment: @Oriol but I suppose it is not available yet? Correct?

Comment: Yes, not available yet.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You can try the below generic method to parse them.

```js
var elm1 = document.querySelector('#target1');
//console.log(parseColor(elm1.style.borderColor));
console.log(formatRGBA(elm1.style.borderColor));

var elm2 = document.querySelector('#target2');
//console.log(parseColor(elm2.style.borderColor));
console.log(formatRGBA(elm2.style.borderColor));

var elm3 = document.querySelector('#target3');
//console.log(parseColor(elm3.style.borderColor));
console.log(formatRGBA(elm3.style.borderColor));



function parseColor(color) {
  var m = color.match(/^rgb\s*\(\s*(\d+)\s*,\s*(\d+)\s*,\s*(\d+)\s*\)$/i);
  if( m) {
     return [m[1], m[2], m[3], '1'];
  }
  
  m = color.match(/^rgba\s*\(\s*(\d+)\s*,\s*(\d+)\s*,\s*(\d+)\s*,\s*((0.)?\d+)\s*\)$/i);
  if( m) {
     return [m[1], m[2], m[3], m[4]];
  }
}

function formatRGBA(color) {
  var component = parseColor(color);
  return 'rgba(' + component.join(',') + ')';
}
```

```html
<div id="target1" style="  width: 150px;  height:150px;  background-color:red;  border-color: rgba(0,255,0,1);   border-width: 20px;   border-style: solid;"></div>
<div id="target2" style="  width: 150px;  height:150px;  background-color:red;  border-color: rgba(0,255,0,0);   border-width: 20px;   border-style: solid;"></div>
<div id="target3" style="  width: 150px;  height:150px;  background-color:red;  border-color: rgba(0,255,0,0.5);   border-width: 20px;   border-style: solid;"></div>
```