# How to convert RGBA to Hex color code using javascript

Tags: javascript, css

I tried to convert `rgba` to hex color code, but unable to covert opacity value remaining color I able to convert,

Below is my code

```js
var colorcode = "rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.74)";

var finalCode = rgba2hex(colorcode)

function rgba2hex(orig) {
    var a, isPercent,
    rgb = orig.replace(/\s/g, '').match(/^rgba?\((\d+),(\d+),(\d+),?([^,\s)]+)?/i),
    alpha = (rgb && rgb[4] || "").trim(),
    hex = rgb ?
    (rgb[1] | 1 << 8).toString(16).slice(1) +
    (rgb[2] | 1 << 8).toString(16).slice(1) +
    (rgb[3] | 1 << 8).toString(16).slice(1) : orig;
  
    if (alpha !== "") { a = alpha; }
    else { a = 01; }
    hex = hex + a;
  
    return hex;
}

console.log(finalCode)
```

Here I need alpha value also convert to hex code.

Please suggest how to convert

**Output**

Expect:000000bd

Comment: The color2color library on github might be what you are looking for: https://github.com/metaloha/color2color

Comment: See https://stackoverflow.com/a/19366389/6782 which will give you an RGBA array that's trivially converted to hexadecimal if required.

Answer (score 33):

Since the alpha channel in your rgba() notation is expressed as a 0 ~ 1 value, you need to multiply it by 255 before trying to convert it to its HEX form:

```js
var colorcode = "rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.74)";

var finalCode = rgba2hex(colorcode)

function rgba2hex(orig) {
  var a, isPercent,
    rgb = orig.replace(/\s/g, '').match(/^rgba?\((\d+),(\d+),(\d+),?([^,\s)]+)?/i),
    alpha = (rgb && rgb[4] || "").trim(),
    hex = rgb ?
    (rgb[1] | 1 << 8).toString(16).slice(1) +
    (rgb[2] | 1 << 8).toString(16).slice(1) +
    (rgb[3] | 1 << 8).toString(16).slice(1) : orig;

  if (alpha !== "") {
    a = alpha;
  } else {
    a = 01;
  }
  // multiply before convert to HEX
  a = ((a * 255) | 1 << 8).toString(16).slice(1)
  hex = hex + a;

  return hex;
}

function test(colorcode) {
  console.log(colorcode, rgba2hex(colorcode));
}

test("rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.74)");
test("rgba(0, 0, 0, 1)");
test("rgba(0, 0, 0, 0)");
test("rgba(0, 255, 0, 0.5)");
```

But note that this is just one of the rgba notation, and that it will e.g fail with percent based notation.
Note also that all browsers do not support RGBA HEX notation, so you might prefer an other method to convert your values depending on what you want to do with it.

Answer (score 7):

Try this:

- ✓ Works with alpha `rgba(255, 255, 255, 0) => #ffffff00`
- ✓ Works with single digits `rgba(0, 0, 0, 0) => #00000000`
- ✓ Works with RGB as well `rgb(124, 255, 3) => #7cff03`
- ✓ You can slice alpha channel away `rgba(255, 255, 255, 0) => #ffffff`

```js
function RGBAToHexA(rgba, forceRemoveAlpha = false) {
  return "#" + rgba.replace(/^rgba?\(|\s+|\)$/g, '') // Get's rgba / rgb string values
    .split(',') // splits them at ","
    .filter((string, index) => !forceRemoveAlpha || index !== 3)
    .map(string => parseFloat(string)) // Converts them to numbers
    .map((number, index) => index === 3 ? Math.round(number * 255) : number) // Converts alpha to 255 number
    .map(number => number.toString(16)) // Converts numbers to hex
    .map(string => string.length === 1 ? "0" + string : string) // Adds 0 when length of one number is 1
    .join("") // Puts the array to togehter to a string
}

//
// Only tests below! Click "Run code snippet" to see results
//

// RGBA with Alpha value
expect(RGBAToHexA("rgba(255, 255, 255, 0)"), "#ffffff00")
expect(RGBAToHexA("rgba(0, 0, 0, 0)"), "#00000000")
expect(RGBAToHexA("rgba(124, 255, 3, 0.5)"), "#7cff0380")
expect(RGBAToHexA("rgba(124, 255, 3, 1)"), "#7cff03ff")

// RGB value 
expect(RGBAToHexA("rgba(255, 255, 255)"), "#ffffff")
expect(RGBAToHexA("rgba(0, 0, 0)"), "#000000")
expect(RGBAToHexA("rgba(124, 255, 3)"), "#7cff03")

// RGBA without Alpha value
expect(RGBAToHexA("rgba(255, 255, 255, 0)", true), "#ffffff")
expect(RGBAToHexA("rgba(0, 0, 0, 0)", true), "#000000")
expect(RGBAToHexA("rgba(124, 255, 3, 0.5)", true), "#7cff03")
expect(RGBAToHexA("rgba(124, 255, 3, 1)", true), "#7cff03")

function expect(result, expectation) {
  console.log(result === expectation ? "✓" : "X", result, expectation)
}
```

Code is built based on:

- https://css-tricks.com/converting-color-spaces-in-javascript/

Answer (score 5):

My solution. Hope be useful.

```
const rgbaToHex = (color: string): string => {
  if (/^rgb/.test(color)) {
    const rgba = color.replace(/^rgba?\(|\s+|\)$/g, '').split(',');

    // rgb to hex
    // eslint-disable-next-line no-bitwise
    let hex = `#${((1 << 24) + (parseInt(rgba[0], 10) << 16) + (parseInt(rgba[1], 10) << 8) + parseInt(rgba[2], 10))
      .toString(16)
      .slice(1)}`;

    // added alpha param if exists
    if (rgba[4]) {
      const alpha = Math.round(0o1 * 255);
      const hexAlpha = (alpha + 0x10000).toString(16).substr(-2).toUpperCase();
      hex += hexAlpha;
    }

    return hex;
  }
  return color;
};
```

Comment: Welcome to Stack Overflow. Code without any explanation are rarely helpful. Stack Overflow is about learning, not providing snippets to blindly copy and paste.
 Please edit your question and explain how it answers the specific question being asked. See [How to Answer](https://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-answer).

Answer (score 3):

Great @kaiido,  i tried this way

```
function rgba2hex(orig) {
      var a, isPercent,
        rgb = orig.replace(/\s/g, '').match(/^rgba?\((\d+),(\d+),(\d+),?([^,\s)]+)?/i),
        alpha = (rgb && rgb[4] || "").trim(),
        hex = rgb ? 
        (rgb[1] | 1 << 8).toString(16).slice(1) +
        (rgb[2] | 1 << 8).toString(16).slice(1) +
        (rgb[3] | 1 << 8).toString(16).slice(1) : orig;
          if (alpha !== "") {
            a = alpha;
          } else {
            a = 01;
          }

          a = Math.round(a * 100) / 100;
            var alpha = Math.round(a * 255);
            var hexAlpha = (alpha + 0x10000).toString(16).substr(-2).toUpperCase();
            hex = hex + hexAlpha;

      return hex;
}
```

Answer (score 2):

If you have the rgba color as a string, you can do something like this.

```
const color = 'rgba(249,6,6,1,0)';
const rgba = color.replace(/^rgba?\(|\s+|\)$/g, '').split(',');

const hex = `#${((1 << 24) + (parseInt(rgba[0]) << 16) + (parseInt(rgba[1]) << 8) + parseInt(rgba[2])).toString(16).slice(1)}`;
console.log(hex); // #f90606
```

Comment: this doesn't cater the alpha channel

Answer (score 2):

Just create a function to be more effective! Code is same as above.

```js
    var color;

    function HexCode(color){
        const rgba = color.replace(/^rgba?\(|\s+|\)$/g, '').split(',');
        const hex = `#${((1 << 24) + (parseInt(rgba[0]) << 16) + (parseInt(rgba[1]) << 8) + parseInt(rgba[2])).toString(16).slice(1)}`;
        
        return hex;
    }

    console.log(HexCode('rgba(0,255,255,0.1)'))
```

Comment: Just tested your function, it doesn't cater for the alpha channel.

Answer (score 2):

Here is a simplified option.

```
function rgbToHex(rgb) {
  return '#' + rgb.match(/[0-9|.]+/g).map((x,i) => i === 3 ? parseInt(255 * parseFloat(x)).toString(16) : parseInt(x).toString(16)).join('')
}
```

Works for rgb and rgba.

Comment: This is almost there, but it doesn't pad single digits with `0`

Its a simple matter of check string length is one and prepending with 0 in that case.

Answer (score 0):

```js
  function rgbaToHex(r, g, b, a) {
  const red = r.toString(16).padStart(2, '0');
  const green = g.toString(16).padStart(2, '0');
  const blue = b.toString(16).padStart(2, '0');
  const alpha = Math.round(a * 255).toString(16).padStart(2, '0');
  return `#${red}${green}${blue}${alpha}`;
}

console.log(rgbaToHex(2,2,2,0.6));
console.log(rgbaToHex(2,2,2,0.50));
```

Answer (score 0):

Try

```js
let hex2rgba= c=> `rgb${c.length>7?'a':''}(${c.match(/\w\w/g).map((x,i)=> (+`0x${x}`)/(i<3?1:255))})`;
let rgba2hex= c=> '#'+c.match(/[\d\.]+/g).map((x,i)=> Math.round((+x)*(i<3?1:255)).toString(16).padStart(2,0)).join``;
```

it supports rgb and rgba format (rgb only [here](https://stackoverflow.com/a/60347125/860099))

```js
let hex2rgba= c=> `rgb${c.length>7?'a':''}(${c.match(/\w\w/g).map((x,i)=> (+`0x${x}`)/(i<3?1:255))})`;
let rgba2hex= c=> '#'+c.match(/[\d\.]+/g).map((x,i)=> Math.round((+x)*(i<3?1:255)).toString(16).padStart(2,0)).join``;

console.log('TEST rgba');
console.log('#d5efabcc             -->', hex2rgba('#d5efabcc'));
console.log('rgba(213,239,171,0.8) -->', rgba2hex('rgba(213,239,171,0.8)'));

console.log('\nTEST rgb');
console.log('#d5efab          -->', hex2rgba('#d5efab'));
console.log('rgb(213,239,171) -->', rgba2hex('rgb(213,239,171)'));
```