# How to get the background color of an element (set to RGBA) in Javascript?

Tags: javascript, html, css

I have an element with the Id `box`, which has a background color set to `rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.3)` on a white background. Like so:

```css
#box {
  width: 100px;
  height: 100px;
  margin: 10px;
  background-color: rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.3);
}
```

```html
<div id="box"></div>
```

Using a color picker, I can see that the box's color is in hex is `#b2b2b2`. Now, what I want to know is there any way to **get** this hex code using JavaScript
without convert `RGBA` to `hex` format? I read about `getComputedStyle` function, but could not get it to work. Any help is greatly appreciated.

Comment: Does this answer your question? [How to convert RGBA to Hex color code using javascript](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/49974145/how-to-convert-rgba-to-hex-color-code-using-javascript)

Comment: @PEPEGA No it does not, because my question is not just converting rgba to hex. Its also reading the background color first.

Comment: Please show how you tried to get `getComputedStyle` to work.

Comment: So you want to get the composited color after all element layers have been rendered?

Comment: Well, it can't really work since what your color picker shows you is a mix of colors. Your box is not really #b2b2b2, it's semi-transparent with something (white I suppose) behind.

Comment: Does this answer your question? [How to get hex color value rather than RGB value?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1740700/how-to-get-hex-color-value-rather-than-rgb-value)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I will consider [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/50574620/8620333) where I am detailing how the color is calculated between two layers to write the following script.

```js
/* Utility function that you can easily find in the net */
function extractRgb (css) {
  return css.match(/[0-9.]+/gi)
}
function rgbToHex(r, g, b) {
  return "#" + ((1 << 24) + (r << 16) + (g << 8) + b).toString(16).slice(1);
}
/**/

var c = window.getComputedStyle(document.getElementById('box')).backgroundColor;
c = extractRgb(c);

for(var i=0;i<3;i++)
  c[i] = parseInt(c[i]*c[3] + 255*(1 - c[3])); /* Check the linked answer for details */

console.log(rgbToHex(c[0],c[1],c[2]) )
```

```css
#box {
  width: 100px;
  height: 100px;
  margin: 10px;
  background-color: rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.3);
}
```

```html
<div id="box"></div>
```

The script can easily be improved but the main idea is the formula uses to calculate the result between two colors:

> `ColorF = (ColorT*opacityT + ColorB*OpacityB*(1 - OpacityT)) / factor`
>
> `ColorF` is our final color. `ColorT`/`ColorB` are respectively the top and bottom colors. `opacityT`/`opacityB` are respectively the top and bottom opacities defined for each color:
>
> The factor is defined by this formula `OpacityT + OpacityB*(1 - OpacityT)`.

Answer (score 0):

I think basically what you are trying to do is comprehend what color the browser renders - which is quite different than what colors your elements' backgrounds are defined with.

As I said in a comment, you have a #box defined with a semi-transparent black color. Depending on what the element "behind" it is, your color picker will read something quite different (compare let's say a red background and a white background behind your #box).

I don't really know how to proceed to get the real rendered color, but I'd start looking at stuff like this, I suppose : https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/WebGLRenderingContext/readPixels

Hope that helps.

Answer (score -3):

Check it out:

```js
$(document).ready(function(){
  alert(componentToHex($('#box').css('background-color')));
});

function componentToHex(c) {
  var hex = c.toString(16);
  return hex.length == 1 ? "0" + hex : hex;
}

function rgbToHex(r, g, b) {
  return "#" + componentToHex(r) + componentToHex(g) + componentToHex(b);
}

alert(rgbToHex(0, 51, 255));
```

```css
#box {
  width: 100px;
  height: 100px;
  margin: 10px;
  background-color: rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.3);
}
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.12.4/jquery.min.js"></script>
<div id="box"></div>
```

Comment: From the OP: "I can see that the box's color is in hex is #b2b2b2. Now, what I want to know is there any way to get this hex code"...

Comment: When I run it, it alerts "#0033ff", then "rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.3)". Neither of those is "#b2b2b2", as my first comment on this answer quotes from the question.

Comment: @Deadpool Because you don't account for the fact the background-color has an alpha value and the color of the first colored parent node?