# Loading string of numbers to array of numbers

Tags: javascript

I am trying to load a background color of a clicked box to the array of rgb.

As you can see when I use `rgb1 = color.split(",")` this creating array of string like

```
[
  "49",
  " 133",
  " 155"
]
```

So I tried to parse the items to int like `rgb2 = parseInt(color.split(","));` but now I am juts getting `49` on return.

How can I export the result like so?

> [49 , 133, 155]

Code:

```js
 $(".box").on("click", function () {

  color = $(this).css("background-color").substring(4).slice(0,-1);

  rgb1 = color.split(",");
  rgb2 = parseInt(color.split(","));
  
  console.log(color);
  console.log(rgb1);
  console.log(rgb2);
  
});
```

```css
.box{
    height:30px;
    width:30px;
    background:#31859B;
}
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<div class="box"></div>
```

Comment: See https://stackoverflow.com/questions/10970958/get-a-color-component-from-an-rgb-string-in-javascript

Comment: parseInt(["49","133","155"]) will try to build a string out of that array, so it will do parseInt("49,133,155"), which is then parsed to 49

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You could use a regular expression which matches only the number parts. Then convert the strings to number.

```js
var color = "49, 133, 155",
    parts = color.match(/\d+/g).map(Number);

console.log(parts);
```

Answer (score 0):

```js
$(".box").on("click", function () {

  color = $(this).css("background-color").substring(4).slice(0,-1);

  rgb1 = color.split(",");
  rgb2 = [];

  for (var i = 0; i < rgb1.length; i++) {
    rgb2[i] = parseInt(rgb1[i]);
  }
  console.log(rgb2);
  
});
```

```css
.box{
    height:30px;
    width:30px;
    background:#31859B;
}
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<div class="box"></div>
```