# Quick Regex/Replace for rgba(..) from various rgb/rgba strings

Tags: javascript, jquery, regex

I have various color definitions as follows,

```
i.cat1{background:rgb(249, 115, 0);}  // RGB with 3 params
i.cat2{background:rgba(14, 48, 71, 0.99);}  // RGBA with 4 params
```

My goal is to set a new `rgba(x,y,z,opacity)` with a pre-defined opacity variable, say 0.4 (regardless of previous opacity if existed); but `x,y,z` from the existing values, which are guaranteed to exist.

Ex.

```
from #1:   rgb(249,115,0)      --> rgba(249,115,0,0.4)
from #2:   rgba(14,48,71,0.99) --> rgba(14,48,71,0.4)
```

Any quick regex solutions, other than parsing the tokens inside the parentheses and checking if it's 3 or 4 params?

Of course, we can do `str.replace('rgb(', 'rgba(');` as the first step, but I just want a quick 4-param expression.

**Assume I'm getting the current color as a string, say `var color` is the original str, so this is a regexp question.**

Comment: Are you planning on doing this in some sort of an editor or what?  I'm confused why you are wanting to use javascript to do this.

Comment: I'm using JS to modify the background color string dynamically in code. What are other solutions for setting opacity, via CSS?

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Get a color component from an rgb string in Javascript?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/10970958/get-a-color-component-from-an-rgb-string-in-javascript)

Comment: How dynamic are the background colors?  Could you modify your script to instead of setting inline styles, to use classes instead?  Which can be more easily swapped in and out, and the stylesheet updated to fit your needs.  Edit: FWIW, your first paragraph looks like a css rule, which is why I assumed you were asking about a regex to update your stylesheet.

Comment: `rgba?\((\s*\d+\s*),(\s*\d+\s*),(\s*\d+\s*)(,\s*[\d+.]+\s*)?\)`

Comment: `rgb\(\s*(\d+)\s*,\s*(\d+)\s*,\s*(\d+)\s*\)|rgba\(\s*(\d+)\s*,\s*(\d+)\s*,\s*(\d+)\s*,\s*(0\.\d+|[01])\s*\)`?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

```js
var test = [
    "rgb(249,115,0)",
    "rgba(14,48,71,0.99)",
];
console.log(test.map(function (a) {
  return a.replace(/rgba?(\(\s*\d+\s*,\s*\d+\s*,\s*\d+)(?:\s*,.+?)?\)/, 'rgba$1,0.4)');
}));
```

Answer (score 3):

I think this regex suits your needs :

```
rgba?\((\s*\d{1,3}\s*,\s*\d{1,3}\s*,\s*\d{1,3}\s*)((?:,\s*[0-9.]*\s*)?)\)
```

See this [Regex101.com](https://regex101.com/r/RZOPEC/3) with the substitution result.

Answer (score 2):

Here's my attempt

`rgba?(\(([\d\s]+,?){3})(,[\d\s.]+)?(?=\))` replacing with `rgba$1,0.4`

```js
var tests = ['rgb(249,115,0)','rgba(14,48,71,0.99)'];
var regex = /rgba?(\(([\d\s]+,?){3})(,[\d\s.]+)?(?=\))/;
var replace = 'rgba$1,0.4';

tests.forEach(test => {
  console.log(test.replace(regex, replace));
})
```